# Detect "Delay write failed" occurence

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I am loosing my patience with "delay write failed" errors. It silently disconnects the database from the application so nothing gets saved in the database while using it. Is there a way to detect the occurrence itself so I can flash a warning ? Or perhaps monitoring the connection itself for a disconnection ? Everyone seems to miss the balloon tip from the Windows XP so I figured to flash a more visible warning that the application must be restarted. It seems Microsoft has found a way to force people to upgrade....
I suppose this could be done with a timer and constantly check connected users:

```
cxlabel1.Caption := IntToStr(DataModule2.ABSDatabase1.GetDBFileConnectionsCount);
```

But I was thinking more of checking/detecting for the occurence itself. Is there something in Delphi that can detect this?
I would like to hear your ideas on this...

Comment: What are you doing when this situation arises? - *It silently disconnects the database from the application* : what's "it" and "the database" ? what type of connection?

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing "Delayed Write Errors" on a regular basis unless you're running in a very disk/network hostile environment.  Without a good reason for that, you need to worry about fixing the PCs first before worrying about coding around it.

Comment: Its a small multiuser database done with absolute database as the back-end database. The problem is that when the disconnection occurs windows xp flash the delay write balloon tip but the users seems to miss this. So they just keep on writing to the database as if nothing happened. They "see" the entered information in the grid but the problem is that nothing is actually written into the database. So if you close the programm everything you entered from the delay write error is lost forever. @afrasier - you are right... this is a a very disk/network hostile env. but I am not the network admin.

Comment: That's why I am also reluctant to use a timer. It just adds unnecessary traffic making the situation worse. So I will probably  have to use some other event for the occasion. The error does not come very often but when it does it can cause damage.

Comment: Without changing where you write the data, I think you can do nothing more than to educate the users not to pull the flash drive out. Users make mistakes. When they do, educate them. They learn and stop making them. You don't have to prevent every single type of user error.

Comment: @Alex K. - When the thing happens, I print the contents of the grid and then restart the application. Then I compare the information in the grid with the one printed.

Comment: @David Heffernan -I agree with you 100% but some people just don't get it.... Very frustrating...Then people think there's something wrong with your application and not the network.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this as an answer because the comment length is limited.

I have seen this before. IIRC, the problem you have is that the Delayed Write Error is an OS error, it has nothing to do with your application. Windows has already told you that the write has been committed correctly to disk. You would have to try and hook into the OS errors to see when this is happening.

You need to get the network issues resolved because that's where the problem is. In our situation it was a faulty router that was causing the problem.

It's unfair to expect users to check for the error message and then handle it. They could be out at lunch when it occurs as it's not immediate. They also have no way of know what has been saved and what hasn't. It's only a matter of time before your database is corrupted.

The problem with a timer is that it might tell you everything is fine because it triggers after the network resolves the problems.

A far better approach would be to switch to a Client/Server database. You can do this by setting up your own server that listens for web service or another remote call or switch to a database that supports client/server instead of using a file based database. This will tell you immediately when there is a problem with the save of data.